# Using dbgview with java

Tags: java, eclipse, log4j, sysinternals, debugview

I am writing java code and would like to use dbgview (and log4j if possible). By searching the documentation of log4j it seems that unlike log4net, log4j does not support the `OutputDebugStringAppender` which redirect output to what dbgview listens to.

How can one create a log file that dbgview can parse?
How can one send string to the debug stream from java?
Is there any debugview alternative for java?

I am using eclipse, Windows 7 and latest log4j jar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java does not have a native functionality to send over debug prints to Windows debug output.

However you can easily do it by importing the Windows OutputDebugString function using JNA. It will break any multi-platform functionality (you will only be able to run on windows) but it will work.

You can do something like this :

```
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;

public interface Kernel32 extends Library
{
    public void OutputDebugStringA(String Text);
}
```

When calling OutputDebugString you need to do this :

```
 Kernel32 lib = (Kernel32) Native.loadLibrary(“kernel32″, Kernel32.class);
 lib.OutputDebugStringA(message);
```

Comment: So basicly what I should be doing is add a log4j handler that uses the function you specified. Thank you :)